# Problem with sorting array algorithm

Tags: arrays, fortran, sorting, fortran95

I have three arrays. And I am trying to sort all of them by one of them so. So my arrays are itemarray, pricearray, quantityarray. I want itemarray to be sorted but the corresponding arrays aren't sorting appropriately along with itemarray.

Here is the algorithm I created. Do you know how I can fix this??

```
DO i=1, NumItems-1

    SmallestItem = MINVAL(itemarray(i:NumItems))
    MINLOC_array = MINLOC(itemarray(i:NumItems))
    Locationsmallest = (i-1)+MINLOC_array(1)

    itemarray(Locationsmallest) = itemarray(i)
    itemarray(i) = SmallestItem

    pricearray(Locationsmallest) = pricearray(i)
    pricearray(i) = SmallestItem

    quantityarray(Locationsmallest) = quantityarray(i)
    quantityarray(i) = SmallestItem

END DO
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting `pricearray(i)` to something that came from `itemarray`. You should be swapping `pricearray(Locationsmallest)` and `pricearray(i)`, which you can do by storing the value of `pricearray(Locationsmallest)` in a temporary variable.

The same is true for `quantityarray(i)`.

By the way, this is an O(n^2) algorithm, and is likely to be very slow when there are a large number of values in your array.

Comment: Should the temporary variable be something like this: pricearray(locationsmallest)=pricesmallestitem I'm having difficulty with the logic.

Comment: @EuropaDust: Something like: temp = pricearray(Locationsmallest); pricearray(Locationsmallest) = pricearray(i); pricearray(i) = temp. (Replace semi-colons with newlines.) But I confess I do not know Fortran syntax, so you may need to tweak this slightly

Comment: It's actually perfectly fine fortran, even with the semicolons included.